# Align centre footer with left and right footers with fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

I have the following set up in a particular document:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

% -- Header and footer --------------------------------------
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength{\footskip}{32pt}
\rfoot{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{figures/Gradient1}}
\lfoot{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{figures/Gradient2}}
\cfoot{
   \tiny{Some really long piece of text that needs to \\ 
         be positioned at the centre of the footer}
   \\
   \normalsize{\thepage}}
```

Which produces the following footer:

[image]

The left and right footer are not vertically aligned with the centre footer. The images are nearly pegged to the text, skipping the space between main text and footer. Instead I would expect something like:

[image]

Can it be done somehow?

Comment: please see if the answer below fulfills the requirement -- `makecell` package is used to split the lines of text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `\parbox` with bottom alignment for the center foot. Since images are positioned with the bottom on the baseline, you get automatically what you wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% -- Header and footer --------------------------------------

\setlength{\footskip}{48pt} % fancyhdr suggests at least 37.74333pt
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-1x1}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\includegraphics[height=12mm]{example-image-1x1}}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \parbox[b]{\textwidth}{%
    \centering
    {\tiny Some really long piece of text that needs to \\ 
           be positioned at the centre of the footer\\}
    \thepage
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it is the most elegant. But the others are worth a look too.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{} % Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.22,valign=c]{example-image}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\begin{tabular}
        {@{}c@{}}
        \tiny {\makecell[c]{Some really long piece of text that\\ needs to  
        be positioned at the centre of the footer}}\\ \normalsize{\thepage}
    \end{tabular}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\includegraphics[scale=0.22,valign=c]{example-image}}

%\setlength{\footskip}{60pt}% Depends on image size

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to obtain the desired effect inserting a vertical space before the figures. The catch is this being a negative space:

```
\rfoot{\vspace{-3mm}\includegraphics[height=12mm]{figures/Gradient1}}
\lfoot{\vspace{-3mm}\includegraphics[height=12mm]{figures/Gradient2}}
```